# show local weather using openweathermap api on GitHub pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, api, web-applications

I create a simple weather web app using HTML +CSS + JS with API Key from "OpenWeatherMap.org"
it use browser location permission to get correct temperature , 
I test it locally and it working fine , but when upload to GitHub pages the site request location permission but temperature is not appear ?!

this is site folders on GitHub

https://github.com/MoSalem84/weatherApp

and this is link of web app

https://mosalem84.github.io/weatherApp/

so what is wrong that case web app unable to fetch location info?

Comment: The API key is missing: `let api = \`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&appid=${key}\`;`

Comment: hello , i  already  declared variable of key ,const key = "82005d27a116c2880c8f0fcb866998a0";

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '==='` now, check your copy/paste.

Comment: I fix the error in JS file but still not working in GitHub pages

Comment: You're calling an HTTP API on a HTTPS server. Google Chrome prevents this. Try changing: `let api = \`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&appid=${key}\`;`

Comment: ok i modify it but get error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()"

Comment: Works fine to me. Delete your cache and retry

Comment: It working also for me , thanks for help :)